# Displaying total array elements for array being built by form

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I'm currently in a JavaScript course that is asking me to have the following happen:

1. User enters names one at a time into a form, then presses Submit
2. The names are stored into an array and output to a table
3. As names are entered (and added to the table), a total must update as well--based on the array, not just from counting table elements

My current issue is I'll add one name, then the total shows "1"--when I add a second name, the total displays "11"

This is currently what my JavaScript code looks like:

```
function displayNamesAndTotal() {
// Your code goes in here.
var userInputName       = [];
var totalNamesEntered   = [];
var countTotal          = 0;
var firstName;
var arrayIndex;
var output;
var outputTotal;
var form;

form                = document.getElementById("userFormId");
output              = document.getElementById("userEntriesId");
outputTotal         = document.getElementById("testId");
//userInputName[0]  = form.firstname.value;

userInputName.push(form.firstname.value)

for (arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < userInputName.length; arrayIndex++) {

    output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + userInputName[arrayIndex] + "</td></tr>";
    countTotal += userInputName.length; 
}

outputTotal.innerHTML += countTotal;
return false;   

}
```

I've spent the past day or so trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong--and it's probably something embarrassingly easy--but I'm at a loss and could use guidance

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Ugh, I have an idea of what I'm doing wrong, but I don't know how to fix it :(
What I need to do is push form data into my empty array (to fill it).  However, I'm starting to realize it's not actually continuously ADDING more elements to the array, it's just treating it as if it's constantly the first length.

Could anyone explain how I push my form data (from onsubmit) into my array, and keep adding values as the button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your total is storing a string instead of a number. Try using parseInt(number) to convert the string into a number.

Answer (score 1):

Good grief, from reading the other answers from you guys I think I have it licked

```
for (arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < userInputName.length; arrayIndex++) {    
    tableData = "<tr><td>" + userInputName[arrayIndex] + "</td></tr>";
    totalCount = userInputName.length;
}

output.innerHTML += tableData;
outputTotal.innerHTML = "<h4>Total Number of Strings: " + totalCount + "</h4>";

form.string.select();
return false;
```

This way the totalCount acted as the array's length when it went through the loop, then outside in the innerHTML statement I could display it and have it constantly update whenever a new string was submitted.

Thank you for all of your feedback

Answer (score 0):

outputTotal.innerHTML is a string, so adding to it would concatenate the strings together. Since outputTotal.innerHTML starts out as null, add 1 to it creates "1". When you add 1 to it again, outputTotal.innterHTML is already "1", so it becomes "11".

Instead of incrementing outputTotal.innerHTML try setting the HTML to it directly.

```
outputTotal.innerHTML = countTotal;
```

Comment: Question: when I'm adding new data to the array (and to the table), shouldn't this be increasing the length property?  And by that case, wouldn't it work to have that act as the total, or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right. I was just working off of your original syntax of: outputTotal.innerHTML += countTotal
I edited my answer to reflect this.